# Don't understand why tweak changes inference from distributed RAM to block RAM

Tags: verilog

In ISE 14.7 with the following code, the synthesizer infers distributed RAM, with warning xst:3218 citing an asynchronus read

```
always @ (posedge DataOutClock) begin
    if (FillingBankA) begin
        DataOut <= MemoryBankB[MemoryReadAddress];
    end
    else begin
        DataOut <= MemoryBankA[MemoryReadAddress];
    end
end
```

but changing to:

```
always @ (posedge DataOutClock) begin
    if (FillingBankA) begin
        TempDataOutB <= MemoryBankB[MemoryReadAddress];
        DataOut <= TempDataOutB;
    end
    else begin
        TempDataOutA <= MemoryBankA[MemoryReadAddress];
        DataOut <= TempDataOutA;
    end
end
```

causes the inference to switch, as intended to block ram.

I am struggling to see why inserting a register between the RAM and the module output reg port DataOut is having this effect. The temporary register is causing a one clock delay in getting the output

Comment: One clock delay getting output is what the BlockRam does! So if your code doesn't allow it, it can't be synthesised to BlockRAM.

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure I follow. I get one extra clock cycle delay when looking at the simulation, when running the code that uses distributed RAM, vs the code that uses block ram.

Comment: @user202474 The second version adds an extra cycle of latency. Possibly the block RAM has that much latency, so if you ask for less latency it can't use block RAM.

Comment: @user253751 you are correct : but there's no "possibly" about it. The BlockRam documentation will confirm its synchronous operation. Hence the XST warning quoted in the question for asynchronous code.

Comment: @user_1818839 `@ (posedge DataOutClock)` doesn't seem very asynchronous? or would it have to be synchronous `MemoryReadAddress` register followed by async RAM?